# Compress the data sent via a C# socket?

Tags: c#, sockets, stream, compression

I'm trying C# sockets to send images. It works, but it's unstable. The images sent through are quite large and are updated very quickly which causes it to flicker every now and then. I'm looking for a way to compress the data sent if possible. I'm using this code:

**Server side:**

```
System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

// !! Code here that captures the screen !!

bitmap.Save(stream, myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters);

byte[] imageBytes = stream.ToArray();
stream.Dispose();

// Send the image
clientSocket.Send(imageBytes);

// Empty the byte array?
for (int i = 0; i < imageBytes.Length; i++)
{
    imageBytes[i] = 0;
}
```

**Client side:**

```
private void OnConnect(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Connected");

        //Start listening to the data asynchronously
        clientSocket.BeginReceive(byteData,
                                    0,
                                    byteData.Length,
                                    SocketFlags.None,
                                    new AsyncCallback(OnReceive),
                                    null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Stream Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}

private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        int byteCount = clientSocket.EndReceive(ar);

        // Display the image on the pictureBox
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteData);
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
    catch (ArgumentException e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
    clientSocket.BeginReceive(byteData,0,byteData.Length,SocketFlags.None,new AsyncCallback(OnReceive),null);
}
```

Comment: Do your images compress well with `gzip`? Is it fair game to re-encode the images using a lossy format such as JPEG?

Comment: "flickering" has *nothing* to do with sending data over a socket.  You presumably just need to leverage [double buffering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics).

Comment: I'll have a look at gzip, thanks. Also the flickering is green/blue and makes the image distorted or out of place. It's not like normal flickering when it needs double buffering. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using gzip.

Turns out the flicker wasn't due to it being updated very quickly, but was because of the way I had sockets set up. It wasn't sending the whole image.